# The last item can't show when RecyclerView in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I found that my last item in `RecyclerView` can't show when `RecyclerView` inside `GridLayot`.

I try to remove `GridLayot` and just use `RecyclerView`, and it can show all items, but I can't use these solution because I need to show my `AppBarLayout` too. So I need to use `GridLayot` to make `AppBarLayout` and `RecyclerView` be a group, and `SwipeRefreshLayout` can use.

How can I fix that, thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">


    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorComtGray">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:rowCount="2">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_row="0">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_user_cost_diamond_icon"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_point" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_user_cost_diamond_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </GridLayout>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make recyclerview row 1

```
           <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
             android:layout_row="1"
            android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

or Use your layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">


<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:rowCount="1">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_row="0">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_user_cost_diamond_icon"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_user_cost_diamond_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/background"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



        </GridLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/activity_cost_diamond_history_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```